# Error opening serial USB port for communication

Tags: python-3.x, windows, libusb, usbserial

I am trying to establish communication with electrical test equipment for remote control and data logging with a python script. I am unable to even get off the ground. It looks like I am unable to open the port? Any help is appreciated.
I am on a Windows machine using VSCode terminal.

```
PS C:\Users\AaronVaughan> py -m serial.tools.list_ports
COM6
1 ports found
```

```py
>>> import serial                          
>>> ser = serial.Serial(port="COM6")
...        
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM6': FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified.', None, 2)
```

Comment: It seems like you don't have a `COM6` serial port on your system. Try opening `COM1`, for example.

Comment: I tried COM1 and got the same error
```
PS C:\Users\AaronVaughan> py -m serial.tools.list_ports
COM6
1 ports found

```
It seems to find the port here as COM6 right?

Comment: Yep. Perhaps the account you are using doesn't have sufficient privileges. Try testing with  another account.

Comment: Ahh, when I unplug the device, COM6 is still there in the device manager. I likely need a driver from the manufacturer. I'll check and get back to you. Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: I hope it works. :-)

Comment: Yep. Okay so, the drivers for [many] electrical test equipment is handled by NI (National Instruments). After using their app to determine the device name, serial number, and version, I was able to get control remotely using pyvisa.

Answer (score 0):

After acquiring the address, serial number, and version of the instrument, I gained access using pyvisa and libusb1. The address, SN, and ver. were acquired after driver installation from National Instruments and the device manufacturers website.

Some skeleton code below...

```
import pyvisa

rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager()

PM1 = rm.open_resource("USB0::0x0A69::0x0879::63212AL00409::INSTR")
PM1.write_termination = '\n'
PM1.read_termination = '\n'
PM1.timeout = 1000
PM1.write('*CLS')
print(PM1.query('*IDN?'))
PM1.write('*RST')
```